# Could a robot that can survive at the center of the Earth also survive a nuclear explosion?

Tags: robots, nuclear-weapons, explosions, geophysics

The robot in question is a very large, worm-like mining robot with a huge drill on its front end, built to survive staggering levels of heat and pressure. It's so resiliant, in fact, that it can survive at the center of the Earth for an indefinite amount of time. For refrence, pressure at the center of the earth is around 360 gigapascals, and the temperature is about 6000 degreees celsius (10,800 degrees farenheit).

My question is, how would a robot like this stand up to some of history's largest nuclear bombs, like the tsar bomba or castle bravo?

Comment: could a robot THAT can survive a...

Interesting question but I don't have the physics credentials to answer that.

Comment: How far is your robot from the center of the explosion? It is far easier (=actually possible) to build something that survives a nuclear explosion at a minimum distance than in earths core. Because the latter is completely *impossible*.

Comment: Close to the center of Earth, a robotic worm with no head and tail buried beneath France Switzerland border near Geneva. It ate and pooped nuclear explosion and still kicking today...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.atomicarchive.com/Effects/effects7.shtml), the center of the Earth with its 6000° Celsius seems to be rather chilly when compared to the center of a nuclear explosion

> Temperatures of a nuclear explosion reach those in the interior of the sun, about 100,000,000° Celsius, and produce a brilliant fireball.

That's 6 orders of magnitude more.

If you think of it, during an [underground nuclear explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_nuclear_weapons_testing#Effects), rock immediately around the bomb is vaporized.

> The energy of the nuclear explosion is released in one microsecond. In the following few microseconds, the test hardware and surrounding rock are vaporized, with temperatures of several million degrees and pressures of several million atmospheres. Within milliseconds, a bubble of high-pressure gas and steam is formed. The heat and expanding shock wave cause the surrounding rock to vaporize, or be melted further away, creating a melt cavity. The shock-induced motion and high internal pressure cause this cavity to expand outwards, which continues over several tenths of a second until the pressure has fallen sufficiently, to a level roughly comparable with the weight of the rock above, and can no longer grow.

I would say that your robot will turn to plasma anyway, then the blast will disperse it around.

Comment: That's 100million just for a very brief moment. A few minutes later that temperature is much lower. An ablative heat shield might withstand that, but melt after a few minutes at 6000 degrees.

Answer (score 9):

That depends on the distance, of course.

- Nuclear weapons also have a strong radiation pulse. Usually heat and blast are lethal on a similar radius, but if the robot is resistant against heat and blast there is still radiation.
- A contact explosion would be much hotter than what you describe.
- The blast wave might pick the robot up and throw it around. Pressure resistance is not the same as resistance to being shaken.

Comment: The very rapid change in temperature might also be more destructive than the gradual changes for which the robot would be designed.

Comment: Agree with this answer. If you shake an egg, you may not crack the shell, but you can scramble the yolk.